# Painting with PYQT - MouseEvent uses wrong coordinates

Tags: python, pyqt, qpainter

My Problem is: The coordinates where my mouse is and where the painting starts is wrong.
The Canvas starts on the top left corner (0,0) but the label are on somewhere at 250,500(Because ive done this with the designer)

so if draw i have to draw outside the label to get something in the canvas :( I didnt find the problem.

Here is my Code:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QImage, QPen, QPainter, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

from ui.main import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        
        self.main = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.main.setupUi(self)
        path = "G:/SoftwareDevelopement/SignInPrototyp/signin.png"  
        self.main.labelSign.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(path))
        #self.main.labelSign.move(250,410)
        
        

        
        self.drawing = False
        self.brushSize = 2
        self.brushColor = Qt.black
        self.brushStyle = Qt.SolidLine
        self.brushCap = Qt.RoundCap
        self.brushJoin = Qt.RoundJoin
        
        self.last_x, self.last_y = None, None
        
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        
        print(e.x)
        print(e.y)
        if self.last_x is None: # First event.
            self.last_x = e.x()
            self.last_y = e.y()
            return # Ignore the first time.

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.main.labelSign.pixmap())
        
        painter.setPen(QPen(self.brushColor, self.brushSize, self.brushStyle, self.brushCap, self.brushJoin))
        painter.drawLine(self.last_x, self.last_y, e.x(), e.y())

        painter.end()
        self.update()

        # Update the origin for next time.
        self.last_x = e.x()
        self.last_y = e.y()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, e):
        self.last_x = None
        self.last_y = None


# Open and Exit main Window       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    global app
    global window
    # SCALE TO ALL RESOLUTIONS! 1
    os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"
    # AND THIS
    app.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
    
    window = MainWindow()

    window.raise_()
    window.showMinimized()
    #window.show()
    window.showNormal()
    window.activateWindow()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
######################!
```

[This dont work, i have to draw on the left top corner to get inside the white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIs2y.png)

Answer (score 1):

so i got after long trial and error and solution:

```
       painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.main.labelSign.pixmap())
       painter_map = self.main.labelSign.geometry()
       painter.setWindow(painter_map
```

simple remap.

Answer (score 0):

Point 0,0 of window is at top left corner of window, point 0,0 of label is at top left corner of label, you use window coordinates to draw on label (you overriden window event not label event), this two coordinate systems are not equal and to go from one to another you need to translate coordinates. For example like this:

```
offset = self.main.labelSign.pos()
painter.drawLine(self.last_x - offset.x(), self.last_y - offset.y(), e.x() - offset.x(), e.y() - offset.y())
```

You can make your drawable label self contained by creating class that inherits from QLabel and overrides mouseMoveEvent and mouseReleaseEvent, this way you dont need to translate coordinates.

Comment: Alternatives: 1. use an event filter; 2. translate the painter (`painter.translate(-offset)`); 3. use [`mapFrom()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mapFrom).

Comment: i found an alternative thing
       painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.main.labelSign.pixmap())
        painter_map = self.main.labelSign.geometry()
        painter.setWindow(painter_map